# On subadditive functions everywhere finite bounded on compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, semigroup-of-operators

[image]In the book "Functional analysis and Semi-Groups" by E Hille and R S Phillips, theorem 7.4.1 states that subadditive functions defined on some interval $I$  and finite everywhere are bounded over compact sets $I^*\subset I$.
The proof in this book is kind of rough and I have been trying to make another proof - more elegant and/or with a different approach but I get nothing. I would appreciate any reference of another proof or another proof itself. Thank you.

Comment: Could you give us the proof given by the authors? It would also help to show what parts of the proof you find rough or unclear.

Comment: @Shiva I added the proof on an image, is not like the proof is unclear, but "weird", like for instance of the (2,5) interval. I feel you can get a more elegant proof on this but I can't figure it out.